# URLs and cloud providers

Tags: cloud

Lets say that there is the url `www.example.com`
This url holds an web application with a cloud provider other than Google.

Lets say there is a second url, an extension of the first url: `www.example.com/extension_url`
This second url holds a second web application which has no relation to the web application under the first, main url.

Remembering that `www.example.com` is with another cloud provider, can Google Cloud host `www.example.com/extension_url`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not read our documentation on [how to ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), and as a result has asked a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

That depends a bit on how www.example.com is hosted and how much control you have as an administrator. It is not uncommon to run a **reverse proxy** that incorporates content/functionality from a remote server/service and maps that to a local URL such as `www.example.com/extension_url`.

Suppose the local server is running [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass); then

```
<Location /extension_url/>
    ProxyPass http://google-backend.example.com/
</Location>
```

will cause a local request for `http://www.example.com/extension_url/bar` to be internally converted into a proxy request to `http://google-backend.example.com/bar`.

Comment: `ProxyPassReverse` may be required for some setups. If proxied app sets up Base etc. one has to rewrite that.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation `www.example.com` will point to the Google Cloud's server. Therefore everything within the hostname must be hosted here, you cannot have `www.example.com/extension_url` to be hosted on another server.

You have two real options:

1. Add a subdomain pointing to the another hosting, e.g. `secondapp.example.com`. If you need address `www.example.com/extension_url`, you can redirect it to `secondapp.example.com`.
2. If the second application is not a service but you have access to the source code, you should be able to move it to same hosting.

Please don't use `frameset` for this despite guided somewhere: *we are not in the '90s anymore*.